# how to get data from datatable by ( select and Group By)

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have the following data:

```
+--------+-------+-------+
| xMonth | xYear | xMtbk |
+--------+-------+-------+
|    1   |  2020 | Mtbk1 |
+--------+-------+-------+
|    1   |  2020 | Mtbk1 |
+--------+-------+-------+
|    1   |  2021 | Mtbk1 |
+--------+-------+-------+
|    2   |  2020 | Mtbk1 |
+--------+-------+-------+
|    2   |  2021 | Mtbk1 |
+--------+-------+-------+
|    2   |  2021 | Mtbk1 |
+--------+-------+-------+
|    1   |  2020 | Mtbk2 |
+--------+-------+-------+
|    1   |  2021 | Mtbk2 |
+--------+-------+-------+
|    2   |  2020 | Mtbk2 |
+--------+-------+-------+
|    2   |  2021 | Mtbk2 |
+--------+-------+-------+
|    2   |  2021 | Mtbk2 |
+--------+-------+-------+
|    2   |  2021 | Mtbk2 |
+--------+-------+-------+
```

I need to get the next table:

```
+--------+-------+-------+--------+
| xMonth | xYear | xMtbk | xCount |
+--------+-------+-------+--------+
|    1   |  2020 | Mtbk1 |    2   |
+--------+-------+-------+--------+
|    2   |  2020 | Mtbk1 |    1   |
+--------+-------+-------+--------+
|    1   |  2021 | Mtbk1 |    1   |
+--------+-------+-------+--------+
|    2   |  2021 | Mtbk1 |    2   |
+--------+-------+-------+--------+
|    1   |  2020 | Mtbk2 |    1   |
+--------+-------+-------+--------+
|    2   |  2020 | Mtbk2 |    1   |
+--------+-------+-------+--------+
|    1   |  2021 | Mtbk2 |    1   |
+--------+-------+-------+--------+
|    2   |  2021 | Mtbk2 |    3   |
+--------+-------+-------+--------+
```

I have the following code I use it to get the data from already datatable:

```
Dim xGroups = From row In MyVar_Dt_Main
                      Group row By xGroupPar = New With {
                                                    Key .Yr = row.Field(Of Integer)("xYear"),
                                                    Key .Mnth = row.Field(Of Integer)("xMonth"),
                                                    Key .Period = row.Field(Of String)("xMtbk")
                                                } Into Group
                      Select New With {
                                    Key .Dates = xGroupPar,
                                        .SumAmount = Group.Count(Function(x) x.Field(Of String)("xMtbk"))}
```

but I'm facing an error in the following line:

```
.SumAmount = Group.Count(Function(x) x.Field(Of String)
```

the error is:

```
Conversion from string "Mtbk1" to type 'Boolean' is not valid.
```

what is the error and how I get the result into another datatable?

Answer (score 1):

Parameter of `Count()` supposed to be a boolean expression which you can use when you want to count items that satisfy certain condition only. In this case, you seems want to count all items in each group, so just call `Count()` without parameter:

```
.SumAmount = Group.Count()
```

Comment: it's working now but how to get the values for each row with the count value as well?

Comment: I applied the solution but it gives me not Irrational counts.

Comment: anybody can help?

Answer (score 0):

```
.SumAmount = Group.Count(Function(x) x.Field(Of String)
```

Here `Count` is a method that takes an argument, and the argument is a supposed to be a Function that has the DataRow as an argument and returns True or False depending on whether the row is or is not to be counted

You don't need this level of complexity, you simply need to count the number of entries in the group

```
Dim xGroups = From row In MyVar_Dt_Main.Rows
  Group row By xYear = CType(row("xYear"), Int32), xMonth = CType(row("xMonth"), Int32), xMtbk = CType(row("xMtbk"), String)
  Into Count()
```

This works to make an anonymous type that has 4 properties, the xYear, xMonth, XMtbk and Count:

[image]

Your life would get even easier if you used strongly typed datatables:

1. Add a DataSet file, and add a table to it

[image]

2. Look how nice the query is now, no ugly casting:

[image]